# when using context menu in windows explorer xp, selecting multiple files and "open with ->" only opens 1 file

Tags: windows, context-menu

I have a problem with a particular application. However this can be replicated by selecting 2 text files and then "open with"->notepad or wordpad, and only 1 opens...
This is windows xp prof...

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://itmanager.blogs.com/notes/2004/08/eureka_fix_foun.html) may be helpful.